# In C, is it possible to change exported function name to different one?

Tags: c, linker, inline, static-linking

all.

I want to link a library which calls `malloc()` function.
However, my target environment is different one and
`malloc()` is supplied as inline-function.

How can I make the library's call to `malloc()` direct to 
my target environment's `malloc()` routine?

Is it any way to change the exported function name? If so
I can code `my_malloc()` first and export it as `malloc()` and link
the library to that one:

```
#include <my_environment.h>  // malloc() is inline function declared there 
void my_malloc (void) {
   malloc (void);             
}
```

---

More specifically,
the library is one from linux distro so it depends on libc.
But my environment is embedded one and has no libc library and `malloc()`, `free()`, ... are custom-implemented. Some are inline functions and some are library functions.

Comment: On which operating system are you working? If on Linux, learn about `LD_PRELOAD` !

Comment: I work on embedded environment. :-(

Comment: But is it an embedded Linux target operating system? What is the target operating system? How do you link your program??

Comment: Edit the library binary, replacing the character sequence "malloc" with "mylloc"?

Comment: I manually link my program with custom library like this: $ ld -o a.out $(OBJS) -lmy_embedded library

Comment: Thomas/ That's the last thing I want *near-cry*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The GNU linker (ld) supports a `--wrap=functionname` parameter. I'll simply quote the documentation from the man page as it includes an example which should do exactly what you need:

> --wrap=symbol Use a wrapper function for symbol.  Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".  Any undefined reference to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.
>
> This can be used to provide a wrapper for a system function.  The wrapper function should be called "__wrap_symbol".  If it wishes to call the system function, it should call "__real_symbol".
>
> Here is a trivial example:

```
void *
__wrap_malloc (size_t c)
{
    printf ("malloc called with %zu\n", c);
    return __real_malloc (c);
}
```

> If you link other code with this file using `--wrap malloc`, then all calls to "`malloc`" will call the function `"__wrap_malloc`" instead.  The call to "`__real_malloc`" in "`__wrap_malloc`" will call the real "`malloc`" function.
>
> You may wish to provide a "`__real_malloc`" function as well, so that links without the `--wrap` option will succeed.  If you do this, you should not put the definition of "`__real_malloc`" in the same file as "`__wrap_malloc`"; if you do, the assembler may resolve the call before the linker has a chance to wrap it to "`malloc`".

Answer (score 4):

I think the `alias` attribute might solve your problem:

```
alias ("target")
    The alias attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as an alias for another symbol, which must be specified. For instance,

              void __f () { /* Do something. */; }
              void f () __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__f")));


    defines `f' to be a weak alias for `__f'. In C++, the mangled name for the target must be used. It is an error if `__f' is not defined in the same translation unit.

    Not all target machines support this attribute.
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but wouldn't this require having the source code to the library?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I thought he wanted to rename `my_malloc` to `malloc`, so as to make the next `.o` use his inlined `malloc`.

Comment: Yes user1202136. I want that (if possible).

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
#define malloc my_malloc
#include <my_environment.h>
#undef malloc

int malloc(size_t sz)
{
   return my_malloc(sz);
}

#define malloc my_malloc
// use your malloc here
```